# List deleted release asset

Tags: github, github-api

I want to check number of downloads for asset i have deleted. I can get release assets using API : `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:id/assets`, but this call doesn't list deleted assets. 
Documentation doesn't mention any filters that might help me

Is there a way to list deleted assess via github API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub support confirmed, that it's not possible at this moment. And it seems like it won't be available anytime soon...

Answer (score 1):

You can [check with GitHub support](https://github.com/contact), but I suspect the [deletion of a release](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-and-deleting-releases/) or an asset within a release is not something which can be undone or restored.

That means the asset deleted is not "kept" somewhere, and its associated statistics are not kept.